Rounded corners with images behind
I am pretty new to customtkinter and programming as a whole (im in university 1st year) and we need to create an interface. I am trying to round the corners of a button which is on top of an image which I use for the background. The problem is that when I round the corners the button widget cuts off the background image. I put the background color of the widget to be transparent but since it cuts off the screen it turns to black. I want to ask if there is a way to make it so the background doesnt cover the background image.
this is a the code, mind you its pretty simple and the variables are in spanish
 ventana = ctk.CTk()
    ventana.title("Proyecto Andrómeda")
    ventana.geometry("1920×1080")
    ventana.minsize(1920, 1080)
    ventana.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

    # Cargar la imagen de fondo
    fondo_image = Image.open("fondo_inicio.png")
    fondo_photo = ctk.CTkImage(light_image = fondo_image, dark_image = fondo_image, size = (1560, 865))
    
    # Crear un Label y poner la imagen de fondo
    label = ctk.CTkLabel(ventana, image = fondo_photo, text = "")
    label.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    
    # Crear botón de iniciar
    boton_image = Image.open("boton_iniciar.png")
    boton_photo = ctk.CTkImage(light_image = boton_image, dark_image = boton_image, size = (300, 100))
    iniciar_boton = ctk.CTkButton(ventana, command = iniciar_app, image = boton_photo, text = "", fg_color = "#A570AF", corner_radius = 0, hover_color = "#94649D")
    iniciar_boton.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")


CustomTkinter is built on top of Tkinter, and in Tkinter widgets are always opaque rectangles.  So having transparent areas in the corners of a rounded button is fundamentally impossible - and CTk's 'transparent' option is of no help here, it simply copies the (solid) background color from the parent widget.  The only way to achieve the desired appearance would be to draw the rounded button yourself (rather than using a widget), on a Canvas that also contains the background image.
